# Pip install PyQt5 with QML debug flag

Tags: linux, pip, qml, pyqt5, python-3.6

I'm trying to use the QtCreator QML debugging option (via assigned port). I understand it is possible to run a Qt application (in this case - PyQt) with a certain flag, have it block until a connection is established from a client (QtCreator).

(Ubuntu 18.04.01, Python 3.6, PyQt 5.9.2,
PyQt installed via `pip3 install PyQt==5.9.2`)

Run command:
`python3 main.py -qmljsdebugger=port:9030,block`

Resulting in: 
`QML Debugger: Ignoring "-qmljsdebugger=port:9030,block". Debugging has not been enabled.`

So PyQt5 needs to be compiled using the qml_debug flag. Searched around and found nothing PyQt specific. Is there any way to `pip install` PyQt5, and have it compile the C side of the package with the right flag that will enable debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons PyQt5 is distributed by deactivating that flag. If you want to enable it you will have to compile the source code. The different versions of PyQt5 can be found in:

- https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5
- https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/

And following the instructions of the [docs](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html#building-and-installing-from-source) you have to use the flag [`--qml-debug`](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html#cmdoption-configure-py-qml-debug):

```
python configure.py --qml-debug 
make
make install
```